# Asset pipeline route helpers resolving to wrong URL or Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am having trouble with all my asset helpers except for `image_tag` for some reason. They are all generating the wrong paths. I am using Rails 4.0.0 and Ruby 2.0.0. My images are in `/app/assets/images`

e.g.

```
asset_url('this.png')    # -> /this.png
asset_path('this.png')   # -> /this.png
image_url('this.png')    # -> /images/this.png
image_path('this.png')   # -> /images/this.png
image-url('this.png')    # -> /images/this.png
asset-url('this.png')    # -> /this.png
image_tag('this.png')    # -> <img ... src="/assets/this.png" /> <- only correct one
```

I am always given the wrong URL... I need `/assets/this.png` which only seems to be generated by `image_tag`

This happens in `.haml`, `.scss`, `.erb` alike.

I can't find the solution to this problem... anybody seen this before and have the answer?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue as you. I followed [this thread](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/57) and was able to solve it by clearing the `tmp` cache.

```
$ rake tmp:cache:clear
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got a different url from the 'Rails.application.routes.url_helpers' in an erb file and the console. This was the culprit! I left some bite marks in my desk...

Answer (score 1):

image_path has been deprecated.check the [ApiDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_path)

```
Method deprecated or moved
This method is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. The last existing version (v3.2.13) is shown here.

These similar methods exist in v4.0.2:

ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper#image_path
```

For **image_tag**, the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) clearly says `Returns an HTML image tag for the source. The source can be a full path or a file.` 
So in that case path it points to is `/assets/file_name.png`

`whereas for **image_path**`Computes the path to an image asset in the public images directory. Full paths from the document root will be passed through.`
Path is /images/filename.png

Comment: Thanks for explaining the distinction! Is there a helper that computes the full path as the `image_tag` helper does?  I was under the impression that `image_path` would work, as per the examples here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/image_path but my `image_path` is resulting in the `AssetTagHelper` examples and not the `AssetUrlHelper` examples

Comment: Just to clarify: `image_path` is not deprecated, just moved to another module. :)

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem in development with a new Rail 4.2.1 application.  I had:

```css
body
{
    background: #EFEFEF image-url('layouts/background.jpg') no-repeat top center fixed;
}
```

and SASS was happily generating:

```css
body
{
    background: #EFEFEF url('/images/layouts/background.jpg') no-repeat top center fixed;
}
```

After a couple hours of troubleshooting, I found this behavior was caused by a misspelling in the path!  The directory containing the image I wanted was `layout`, not `layouts`.

Once I corrected the path, `url(/assets/layout/background.jpg)` was being  generated as expected.

**Update 12NOV2015**
I ran into this again, this time with an `image_tag()`.  I had the path spelled correctly (the image worked fine in development), but I had ".png" omitted form the file path.  This works fine in development, but apparently not in production.  Once I added the ".png" to the path, the `image_tag()` had the correct path.

This behavior is ridiculous.  Not sure why it reverts to some non-standard path (`/images` instead of `/assets`) instead of throwing an exception (but I haven't bothered to look at the source, either).